# Mostar elementos ArrayList Java

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde debo hacer un programa para un punto de venta. Las funcionalidades son agrear mercancía(nombre,cantidad, precio), vender mercancía y listar inventario. Cada mercancía la agrego a un `ArrayList`. El problema es que a la hora de mostrar los elementos del `ArrayList` solo me muestra el primer elemento. Este es mi código:

CLASE INVENTARIO:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Inventario {

      ArrayList<Mercancia> listaMercancias = new ArrayList<>();

     public  void agregarMercancia(Mercancia objMercancia){
        listaMercancias.add(objMercancia);
    }

     public String listarInventario(){
        for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){
            return "Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad;

        }   

        return null;
    }

     public void venderMercancia(Mercancia objMercancia){

         objMercancia.cantidad -= 1;
         if (objMercancia.cantidad == 0) {
             listaMercancias.remove(objMercancia);
         }
     }
```

CLASE MERCANCIA:

```
public class Mercancia {
    String nombre;
    int cantidad;
    int precio;


    public Mercancia(String nombre, int cantidad, int precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.precio = precio;
    } 


}
```

METODO MAIN:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Mercancia objMercancia1 = new Mercancia("producto1",5,500);
    Mercancia objMercancia2 = new Mercancia("producto2",6,200);
    Mercancia objMercancia3 = new Mercancia("producto3",2,300);

    Inventario objInventario = new Inventario();

    objInventario.agregarMercancia(objMercancia1);
    objInventario.agregarMercancia(objMercancia2);
    objInventario.agregarMercancia(objMercancia3);

    System.out.println(objInventario.listarInventario());
    System.out.println(objInventario.listaMercancias.size());


}
```

Cuando ejecuto el método `size()` me dice que hay 3 elementos que son los que agregue.

Comment: Recomendaría no olvidar la importancia del método `toString()`  en la clase `Mercancia.`

Comment: Marco, es interesante lo que comenta Joel, puedes implementar el método toString() en tu clase Mercancia, agregué esto también en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En `listarInventario` haces un `return`, con lo que se produce el retorno, se sale del método y sólo te devuelve el primer elemento.

Un cambio rápido sería:

```
public void listarInventario(){
    for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad);

    }   
}
```

y en el `main` simplemente:

```
objInventario.listarInventario();
```

Comment: A mi me gusta esta opción y no veo que el voto negativo se justifique. Entiendo que a otros no le gusten que el método haga directamente `System.out.println` como si se tratara de una violación de los principios de POO. Pero siendo que el método se llama `listar...` no lo veo como un problema porque hace precisamente lo que dice que va a hacer. De hecho evita tener que crear una cadena que tal vez sea bien larga y consuma memoria. En ese sentido es más eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te aconsejo que regrese una String utilizando el objeto StringBuilder, quedaría algo así

```
 public String listarInventario(){
    StringBuilder listado = new StringBuilder();
    for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){
        listado.append("Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad);

    }   

    return listado.toString();
}
```

Comment: Semánticamente tiene más sentido hacer el System.out.println dentro, que el método se llama listar, no devolver.

Comment: creo que funcionalmente y orientado a objetos es  mucho mas facíl regresar una string para poderla seguir manipulando si es necesario Saludos...

Comment: Si es por manipular ya tiene el ArrayList original. Un String es un tipo de objeto poco válido para manipular.

Comment: muy cierto sstan lo edito

Comment: @Villegas Quizá también debas modificar la descripción de la respuesta. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Primeramente **tu método esta retornando el valor al leer el primer elemento, por esa razón únicamente obtienes el primer valor**. Te aconsejo concatenar los valores y posteriormente retornar el valor de todos los elementos.

```
  public String listarInventario(){
        String resultado = "";

        for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){
            resultado = resultado + "Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad  +  "\n";

        //También puedes usar el operador +=
        //resultado += "Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad  +  "\n";

        }   

        return resultado ;
    }
```

De esta forma retornara el valor de todos los resultados almacenados en `listaMercancias`, al terminar de obtenerlos en el bucle , en caso de no obtener ningún elemento simplemente retornará un string vació.

**Es recomendable el uso de la clase `StringBuilder` al concatenar cadenas, cuando tenemos información considerable**.

```
  public String listarInventario(){
       StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(); 

        for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){
            resultado.append("Nombre: " + mercancias.nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " + mercancias.cantidad);

        }   

        return resultado.toString();
    }
```

---

Incluso como comenta Joel, puedes implementar el método `toString()` en la clase `Mercancia`

```
public class Mercancia {
    String nombre;
    int cantidad;
    int precio;


    public Mercancia(String nombre, int cantidad, int precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.precio = precio;
    } 

     public String toString(){         
        return "Nombre: " + nombre + "; " + "Cantidad restante: " +cantidad+""; Precio: "+precio;     
     }  


}
```

De esta forma podrías obtener el mismo resultado:

```
  public String listarInventario(){
       StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder(); 

        for(Mercancia mercancias:listaMercancias){

           resultado.append(mercancias.toString());

        }   

        return resultado.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Alguna razón por el -1 ? Es bueno en ocasiones indicar donde es el problema para mejorar respuestas, saludos!